# ylim in hclust plot

Tags: r, plot, dendrogram

I have this simple code to draw a dendrogram but the feature `ylim` seems not to work. So no matter what I set it to it has a y range of [0,0.5] when drawn.

Should I use another parameter for setting the ylim when drawing dendrograms?

```
plot(hclust(total_dist),main=NULL,ylab=NULL,ylim=c(0,1))
```

[image]

Comment: `plot` is base `R` not `ggplot2`.   have a look at `?plot.hclust` for more info

Comment: I can not find something related to have y axis between 0 and 1 in ?plot.hclust

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `as.dendrogram`:

```
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests)/200, "ave")
plot(hc)
plot(hc, ylim = c(0,1))  # negative case
plot(as.dendrogram(hc))
plot(as.dendrogram(hc), ylim = c(0,1))  # positive case
```